# Xcode address sanitizer issue with `UIImage imageNamed:@""`

Tags: ios, xcode, address-sanitizer

When activating address sanitizer in Xcode 8, I do get an issue at the following line of code:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

`imageName` is an NSString, the according image exists in @1x, @2x,
@3x. The address sanitizer issue:

> ```
> =================================================================
> ```
>
> ==2484==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x01d37310 in thread T0
>       #0 0x1fff73 in wrap_free (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A762E-DAAF-46D9-857B-151BAF97D0BB/Example.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib+0x32f73)
>       #1 0x2b50fab5 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x2ab5)
>       #2 0x2b50fbe5 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x2be5)
>       #3 0x2b5463e1 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x393e1)
>       #4 0x2b548307 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x3b307)
>       #5 0x2b548233 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x3b233)
>       #6 0x2b5606db in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x536db)
>       #7 0x2b560233 in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI+0x53233)
>       #8 0x2924b611 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x632611)
>       #9 0x2924b375 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x632375)
>       #10 0x2924baf3 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x632af3)
>       #11 0x28eaf8bd in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x2968bd)
>       #12 0x28d46e45 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x12de45)
>       #13 0x76c4d1 in -[MyClass myMethod] (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C92A762E-DAAF-46D9-857B-151BAF97D0BB/Example.app/Frameworks/XY.framework/XY+0x2e4d1)
>       #16 0x28c2874b in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0xf74b)
>       #17 0x28c284bb in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0xf4bb)
>       #18 0x28c2e5e5 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x155e5)
>       #19 0x28c2bf5d in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x12f5d)
>       #20 0x28c9707f in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x7e07f)
>       #21 0x28e8a505 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x271505)
>       #22 0x28e8cacd in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x273acd)
>       #23 0x28e977a7 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x27e7a7)
>       #24 0x28e8b285 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x272285)
>       #25 0x2c09aebf in  (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices+0x15ebf)
>       #26 0x2558e253 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation+0xd0253)
>       #27 0x2558d517 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation+0xcf517)
>       #28 0x2558c071 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation+0xce071)
>       #29 0x254d799f in CFRunLoopRunSpecific (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation+0x1999f)
>       #30 0x254d77b1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation+0x197b1)
>       #31 0x28c8da55 in  (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x74a55)
>       #32 0x28c88633 in UIApplicationMain (/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit+0x6f633)
>       #34 0x34020aad in  (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x1aad)
>       0x01d37310 is located 0 bytes inside of 34-byte region [0x01d37310,0x01d37332)

When I use a non-existing imageName, then the address sanitizer has no problem with that line.

The problem only seems to affect iOS 8, address sanitizer has no problems on iOS 9 and iOS 10 (latest beta). On iOS 8 it also works when I don't put the image in an asset but directly into the bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode 8 Beta 6 (8S201h).
When setting the Deployment Target of your App to iOS 8.3 calling `UIImage imageNamed:` will crash when the referenced image is coming from an asset catalog. Using `UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:` will not make a difference.

Workarounds:

- Set the deployment target < iOS 8.3. iOS 8.0/.1/.2 works for me, 8.3/.4 keeps crashing
- put the image directly in the apps bundle, not an asset catalog

An example project for this issue can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/benrudhart/CrashUIImage)

Comment: did you open a radar for this issue?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior, I checked the Beta 6 Release notes (http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8_beta_6/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8_beta_6.pdf) and Apple describes a similar issue. They mention that the issue is with 16bit assets:

`Apps with asset catalogs containing 16bit or P3 assets and deploying to iOS 8.4 or earlier will experience memory corruption and likely crash if built with Xcode 8.0.`